# How can I tell what server I'm on in DayZ SA?

Tags: dayz-standalone

When I open DayZ and hit "Play," I think the game connects to a random server.  Once I'm connected to a server, how do I know which one I'm on?  I couldn't find any menu that had the server info so I could let a friend know which one to join.

Comment: While I still don't know how to find the specific server, I have found that if you're friends with someone on Steam, you can right click and join their DayZ server, even though it doesn't tell you specifically which one it is.

Comment: That's the best way to connect to one server with your friends. But you can try to press in Steam menu entry names "Server information" or so. But I'm not sure it will tell you server name.

Answer (score 6):

Find a safe location so you can minimize your game.  Browse to My Documents -> DayZ and open username.DayZProfile with Notepad.  Scroll down to the bottom of the file and it will show you...

LastMPServerName="Name of the last server you connected to"

This is the server you last played on which is the server you are currently in.

Additionally, this is the server you join when you click "Play" and NOT a random server.  This allows you to quickly join the last server you played on if it is available.

This is the only way I have found to find out what server I am currently logged into.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I've come up with is manually selecting a server, and telling my friends the name of the server that I selected to join. I've not personally found a way to get the server name from the server itself.

Answer (score 1):

If your friend goes on the server browser then presses friends it will come up with the server you are on. If he has multiple friends then he will have to click deteails on the bottom right corner of his screen on each server until he sees your name

Answer (score -3):

I wrote a utility that helps - Dayz Last Server - find it on cnet.  Keeps track of the server you are on or were most recently attached to.

Comment: Would you mind including a link?